# android cursor.getBlob not working

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

Hi I tried to store and retrieve image to and from sqlite database. My following codes is not working. I'm not sure what wrong I did. Please help.
I created the database table as follows:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(rollno VARCHAR,
 name VARCHAR,photo BLOB,marks VARCHAR);");
```

then I inserted the fields

`db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('" 
                    + editRollno.getText() + "','" 
                    + editName.getText() + "','" 
                    + imageInByte + "','" 
                    + editMarks.getText()
                    + "');");`

where imageInByte is a byte[] variable which was assigned before from gallery as follows:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
```

when I tried to retrieve an image from db it fails:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='"
                + editRollno.getText() + "'", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            editName.setText(c.getString(1));
            editMarks.setText(c.getString(2));

            byte[] image = c.getBlob(3);
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
            theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);     
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(theImage);

        }
```

Comment: Try writing  `editRollno.getText().toString()` instead of `editRollno.getText()` and do it for all others too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply treat byte arrays as text.
(To use blobs with execSQL, you would have to use blob literals.)

To insert a row, use the [insert method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29), which has [support for byte arrays](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20byte[]%29).