# Why SQLite give an error?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile

Actually, it has worked but I have added Byte[]img and values.put(DB_COLUMN,img)

Although I have solved some problems, I can not solve this problem, I need your help, thank you! (I made note of the mistake.)

MY SQLITE DATABASE CLASS

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DB_NAME = "Rest Check";
private static final int DB_VER = 1;
public static final String DB_TABLE = "Task";
public static final String DB_COLUMN =  "TaskName";
public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT NOT NULL)", DB_TABLE,DB_COLUMN);
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = String.format("DELETE TABLE IF EXISTS &s", DB_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(db);
}

    public void insertNewTask (String task, byte[] img){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DB_COLUMN,task);
        values.put(DB_COLUMN, img);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(DB_TABLE,null,values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();
    }

public void deleteTask(String task){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DB_TABLE,DB_COLUMN + " = ?",new String[]{task});
    db.close();
}

public ArrayList<String> getTaskList(){
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE,new String[]{DB_COLUMN},null,null,null,null,null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN);
 ///////////// ERROR LINE /////////////
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(index));  
///////////// ERROR LINE /////////////


    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return taskList;
}

public Cursor getData (String sql){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    return database.rawQuery(sql, null);

}}
```

MY FIRST ACTIVITY (This section gives an error because of related to SQLite Database)

```
 private void loadTaskList() {
/// ERROR LINE ///
    ArrayList<String> taskList = dbHelper.getTaskList();
/// ERROR LINE ///
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.task_title, taskList);
       /// mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ImageView>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.image6, taskList);
        lstTask1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: you could help us by giving us the exception that is being thrown

Comment: BTW, `values.put(DB_COLUMN,task);
        values.put(DB_COLUMN, img);` does not look right

Comment: No, sorry I should have made myself clearer - please post your stacktrace

Comment: Anyway, a blob is not a String, so don't use getString use getBlob

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811674/android-cursor-getblob-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the [Javadoc for ContentValues](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) it appears that there is nothing wrong with putting `byte[]` content into a `ContentValues` object.  But if you look at your current code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DB_COLUMN, task);
values.put(DB_COLUMN, img);
```

you will see that you are trying to put first a string, then a blob, into the *same* column.  This doesn't make sense, and since your code was working fine before the blob addition, this implies that `DB_COLUMN` is a character column.  So I would recommend that you insert the blob into the appropriate column.  Also, there may be other problems in your code, but my suggestion hopefully will resolve the immediate error you are facing.

**Update:**

If you don't have a BLOB column in your table then you can create one:

```
CREATE TABLE Task (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    TaskName TEXT NOT NULL,
    newimage BLOB
)
```

And then your insertion code would be:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DB_COLUMN, task);
values.put("newimage", img);
```

Comment: I'm confused.  If your table doesn't have a BLOB column, then where did you think you were inserting the BLOB data?

Comment: `String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT NOT NULL)", DB_TABLE,DB_COLUMN);` - can not see a blob here