# SQLite Cursor doesn't work for images

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this method to read book object with that exactly id i want from database, 
but when i try to get data from cursor program stops on image column. I dont exactly understand why. I tried "getBlob", "getString" and then convert to byte array, but it just didnt want to work. Maybe you can advise what i should change in query or maybe in class.

```
public Book readBook(int id){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + table_BOOKS;
            Blob blob = new Blob;
            Cursor cursor = db.query(table_BOOKS, COLUMNS, " id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null, null);


        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Book book = new Book();
        if (cursor != null) {
            book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));
            book.setGenre(cursor.getString(3));
            book.setDescription(cursor.getString(4));
            book.setImage(cursor.getBlob(5));
        }
        return book;
    }
```

And this is my data class for Book, its pretty simple, and for image it goes with byte array.

```
public class Book {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String genre;
    private String description;
    private byte[] image;

    public Book(){}

    public Book(String title, String author, String genre,String description, byte[] image){
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return  id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author){
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getGenre(){
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre){
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public byte[] getImage(){
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image){

        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811674/android-cursor-getblob-not-working

Comment: Thanks that helped, i just changed query

Comment: Storing BLOBs in a db is a **worst practice**. Store the paths to the files, instead.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not really a problem description that anyone can help with. I see you have resolved your issue but as such this does not seem to be useful to anyone else as a question or an answer.

Comment: @KlingKlang can you link some example on that please? And thanks for advice.

Comment: Just store the path as a **string**. When you retrieve the string, you will get the image from the path. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed query to look like this

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + table_BOOKS + " WHERE id ='" + id +"'";


        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
```

and then get cursor.getBlob() and it worked